# How to get rid of non-ascii characters in ruby

Tags: ruby, unicode, cgi, ascii

I have a Ruby CGI (not rails) that picks photos and captions from a web form. My users are very keen on using smart quotes and ligatures, they are pasting from other sources. My web app does not deal well with these non-ASCII characters, is there a quick Ruby string manipulation routine that can get rid of non-ASCII chars?

Answer (score 159):

## Use String#encode

The official way to convert between string encodings as of Ruby 1.9 is to use [String#encode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode).

To simply remove non-ASCII characters, you could do this:

```
some_ascii   = "abc"
some_unicode = "áëëçüñżλφθΩ"
more_ascii   = "123ABC"
invalid_byte = "\255"

non_ascii_string = [some_ascii, some_unicode, more_ascii, invalid_byte].join

# See String#encode documentation
encoding_options = {
  :invalid           => :replace,  # Replace invalid byte sequences
  :undef             => :replace,  # Replace anything not defined in ASCII
  :replace           => '',        # Use a blank for those replacements
  :universal_newline => true       # Always break lines with \n
}

ascii = non_ascii_string.encode(Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options)
puts ascii.inspect
  # => "abce123ABC"
```

Notice that the first 5 characters in the result are "abce1" - the "á" was discarded, one "ë" was discarded, but another "ë" appears to have been converted to "e".

The reason for this is that there are sometimes multiple ways to express the same written character in Unicode. The "á" is a single Unicode codepoint. The first "ë" is, too. When Ruby sees these during this conversion, it discards them.

But the second "ë" is two codepoints: a plain "e", just like you'd find in an ASCII string, followed by a "combining diacritical mark" ([this one](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm)), which means "put an umlaut on the previous character". In the Unicode string, these are interpreted as a single "grapheme", or visible character. When converting this, Ruby keeps the plain ASCII "e" and discards the combining mark.

If you decide you'd like to provide some specific replacement values, you could do this:

```
REPLACEMENTS = { 
  'á' => "a",
  'ë' => 'e',
}

encoding_options = {
  :invalid   => :replace,     # Replace invalid byte sequences
  :replace => "",             # Use a blank for those replacements
  :universal_newline => true, # Always break lines with \n
  # For any character that isn't defined in ASCII, run this
  # code to find out how to replace it
  :fallback => lambda { |char|
    # If no replacement is specified, use an empty string
    REPLACEMENTS.fetch(char, "")
  },
}

ascii = non_ascii_string.encode(Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options)
puts ascii.inspect
  #=> "abcaee123ABC"
```

### Update

Some have reported issues with the `:universal_newline` option. I have seen this intermittently, but haven't been able to track down the cause.

When it happens, I see `Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError: code converter not found (universal_newline)`. However, after some RVM updates, I've just run the script above under the following Ruby versions without problems:

- ruby-1.9.2-p290
- ruby-1.9.3-p125
- ruby-1.9.3-p194
- ruby-1.9.3-p362
- ruby-2.0.0-preview2
- ruby-head (as of 12-31-2012)

Given this, it doesn't appear to be a deprecated feature or even a bug in Ruby. If anyone knows the cause, please comment.

Comment: I'm seeing the code converter not found (universal_newline) for ruby-1.9.3-p429

Comment: Changing the symbol `:universal_newline` to `:UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR` fixes the problem for me.

Comment: This helped me a lot, this was the only thing that was working for me! Thanks Nathan!

Comment: On Ruby 2.5.0 I was experiencing a Encoding::UnknownConversionError when trying to strip out Unicode characters from text.

I fixed this by adding `:undef => :replace,` to the Encoding options hash

Comment: Update for Ruby 2.7.  Add double splat to fix the last argument deprecation warning.  `encode(Encoding.find('ASCII'), **encoding_options)`.

Answer (score 41):

1.9

```
class String
 def remove_non_ascii(replacement="") 
   self.gsub(/[\u0080-\uffff]/, replacement)
 end
end
```

1.8

```
class String
 def remove_non_ascii(replacement="") 
   self.gsub(/[\x80-\xff]/, replacement)
 end
end
```

Comment: This is the simplest way to create an ASCII projection dropping Unicode characters.  It does not create a clean translation and injects multiple replacement chars for a single multi-byte Unicode char.  It was the right tool for my job, though.

Comment: In ruby 1.9, I get an exception of "invalid multibyte escape". To fix it, instead of \x80-\xff, I used \u0080-\u00ff

Comment: . . . but, you need to remove the universal_newline option in ruby build p194 (1.9.3-p194).

Comment: Thank you, finally! (but for me it only worked after negation /[^\u0080-\u00ff]/)

Comment: This is a really bad solution. There are 0x10FF7F non-ASCII chars. This will work for 0.01% of these, and will not cover those mentioned by the OP. If you want to use gsub, the Regexp should be `/[^\x00-\x7F]/`.

Comment: Bad solution removed a space in some cases too

Comment: Removes some characters entirely instead of replacing them with ASCII equivalents (spaces, accenteds) but gets the job done :)

Answer (score 21):

Here's my suggestion using Iconv.

```
class String
  def remove_non_ascii
    require 'iconv'
    Iconv.conv('ASCII//IGNORE', 'UTF8', self)
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks like the legitimate way to convert from Unicode to Ascii.

Comment: For followers iconv was deprecated in 1.9+

Answer (score 8):

If you have activesupport you can use `I18n.transliterate`

```rb
I18n.transliterate("áëëçüñżλφθΩ")
"aee?cunz?????"
```

Or if you don't want the question marks...

```rb
I18n.transliterate("áëëçüñżλφθΩ", replacement: "")
"aeecunz"
```

Note that this doesn't remove invalid byte sequences it just replaces non ascii characters. For my use case this was what I wanted though and was simple.

Comment: super-helpful newer addition to this thread

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of help from @masakielastic I have solved this problem for my personal purposes using the #chars method.

The trick is to break down *each character* into **its own separate block** *so that ruby can fail*.

Ruby *needs* to fail when it confronts binary code etc. If you don't allow ruby to go ahead and fail its a tough road when it comes to this stuff. So I use the String#chars method to break the given string into an array of characters. Then I pass that code into a sanitizing method that allows the code to have "microfailures" (my coinage) within the string.

So, given a "dirty" string, lets say you used `File#read` on a picture. (my case)

```
dirty = File.open(filepath).read    
clean_chars = dirty.chars.select do |c|
  begin
    num_or_letter?(c)
  rescue ArgumentError
    next
  end
end
clean = clean_chars.join("")

def num_or_letter?(char)
  if char =~ /[a-zA-Z0-9]/
    true
  elsif char =~ Regexp.union(" ", ".", "?", "-", "+", "/", ",", "(", ")")
    true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```ruby
class String
  def strip_control_characters
    self.chars.reject { |char| char.ascii_only? and (char.ord < 32 or char.ord == 127) }.join
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
ascii_only_str = str.gsub(/[^[:ascii:]]/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick GS revealed [this discussion](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/176496) which suggests the following method:

```
class String
  def remove_nonascii(replacement)
    n=self.split("")
    self.slice!(0..self.size)
    n.each { |b|
     if b[0].to_i< 33 || b[0].to_i>127 then
       self.concat(replacement)
     else
       self.concat(b)
     end
    }
    self.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I found that but it does not deal with unicode double byte chars right? Well, I will test this one, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't short of removing all characters beside the basic ones (which is recommended above). The best slution would be handling these names properly (since most filesystems today do not have any problems with Unicode names). If your users paste in ligatures they sure as hell will want to get them back too. If filesystem is your problem, abstract it away and set the filename to some md5 (this also allows you to easily shard uploads into buckets which scan very quickly since they never have too many entries).