# Rails: CLEAN special characters from English or Arabic String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

I want to clean special characters from English or Arabic Strings. For example, the "–" in the below example is a special character that displays a "?" when converted to UTF-8.

File name: `1-Mechanical Drawings  – Part 1` should be like `1-Mechanical Drawings  Part 1`.

`السلطات العراقية تعلنé` should be `السلطات العراقية تعلن`, where `é` is special character and should be removed from the string.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you're defining a special character? What makes `é` and `—` special?

Comment: sure. I need to clean the file names before uploading. I'm using transliterate_file_name of the paper-clip. its working fine. the problem is when I run the following gsub to clean the file name. it cleans well but it doesn't clean the special characters.

"1-Mechanical Drawings – Part 1 should be like 1-Mechanical Drawings Part 1".squeeze(" ").gsub(' ', '_').gsub(/\W/,'').downcase

my app is supporting file names in different languages

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268289/how-to-get-rid-of-non-ascii-characters-in-ruby

Comment: I tried the above mentioned approach. with special characters, it also cleans the Arabic characters as well.

Comment: also, currently, we are using ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

This is reinventing the wheel somewhat, but you can do something like this to get the output you say you want in the question:

```
def clean_file name
  result = File.basename(name,".*")
  result.gsub!(/[é–]\s?/,'')
  result
end
```

Replacing the bit within [] with the characters you feel are not appropriate in file names like é etc. But beware two things:

- Using a blacklist approach as above may mean you leave characters you don't want - it's more normal to use a whitelist approach like \W to catch all non-word characters, that works in ruby 1.9 at least, but perhaps is what causes you problems on 1.8
- Leaving spaces in the names could cause you issues, so you should probably remove " " and downcase at least.