# "englify" string, get rid off special symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string-comparison, string-conversion

i wanted to ask a question about converting string.

i am using Rails 4.0.4

And in my database i have values which are in my native language like Rīga or Jēkabpils.
I was wondering if there is some kind of function or other way to convert this words to english symbols/characters like Riga or Jekabpils.

I am wondering this because i would like to do this so i could compare them

like:

```
"Jēkabpils".convert == "Jekabpils"
```

I am asking this purely based on my own interest, i am just wondering if this is even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby method to remove accents from UTF-8 international characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686752/ruby-method-to-remove-accents-from-utf-8-international-characters)

Comment: ok thx Jacob K. I will look in to this

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
require "i18n"
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
s = "Jēkabpils"
puts s
puts I18n.transliterate(s)
```

Output:

```
Jēkabpils
Jekabpils
```

Comment: this more like writing every word a translations, i have like 300 cities in my database and the numbers will grow. Is there a way to do this to a character?