# Sort hash by key, ignoring accents

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash like:

```
dict = { 
  "someKey"        => [ ... ],
  "anotherKey"     => [ ... ],
  "yetAnōtherKéy"  => [ ... ]
}
```

I want a new hash by sorting the original. Sorting should ignore the accents (done by replacing the accented characters with their un-accented version),

```
replacements = [
    ["ā", "a"], ["á", "a"], ["à", "a"], ["ǎ", "a"],
    ["ō", "o"], ["ó", "o"], ["ò", "o"], ["ǒ", "o"],
    ["ī", "i"], ["í", "i"], ["ì", "i"], ["ǐ", "i"],     
    ["ē", "e"], ["é", "e"], ["è", "e"], ["ě", "e"],
    ["ū", "u"], ["ú", "u"], ["ù", "u"], ["ǔ", "u"]
]
```

but the keys in the resulting hash should keep the original keys. How is that possible?

---

I tried

```
dict = Hash[dict.sort_by{|k,v| k}]
```

This works and does sort the hash. However, it doesn't ignore the accents, i.e., the words starting with an accented character go to the bottom.

Another attempt is:

```
replacements.each {|replacement| z.gsub!(replacement[0], replacement[1])}
```

Comment: @cremno Well... that's what I mean I'm not used to Ruby... lol. Just fixed it. :)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon please show a little more context around the `replacements.each` line, it's hard to guess with that line alone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby method to remove accents from UTF-8 international characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686752/ruby-method-to-remove-accents-from-utf-8-international-characters)

Comment: This is not a duplicate since he's asking for an answer in plain Ruby, not in Rails.

Comment: Your code assigning the result to `dict` implies that you want the new hash under the same name as the original. If this is the case, it contradicts your description that you wanted a new hash. You should rather replace the old one.

Comment: @TamerShlash Read the related question, it's about plain Ruby too, although the accepted answer uses the Rails related i18n gem. But there are other answers too. In my opinion these questions are duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Code corrected following Cary Swoveland's comment.

```
replacements = Hash.new{|_, k| k}.merge(replacements.to_h)
dict.sort_by{|k,_| k.gsub(/./, replacements)}.to_h
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `{ |k,_| k.gsub(/./,replacements) }`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Exactly. My shame.

Comment: My guess is you were thinking that initially, which is why you constructed the hash that way, then a funny thing happened on your way to the Forum. btw, it seems that the expression "my shame" is has been pushed aside by "my bad".

Comment: You can also build a hash without default value, i.e. `replacements = replacements.to_h` and substitute the characters via `gsub(/[#{replacements.keys.join}]/, replacements)`

Comment: One could also construct the hash thus: `h = replacements.to_h.tap { |h| h.default_proc = ->(h,k) {k} }`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [unidecoder gem](https://github.com/norman/unidecoder).

```
require 'unidecoder'
Hash[dict.sort_by{|k,v| k.to_ascii }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the sort method by passing in a block in which you first perform your substitutions `gsub` (if necessary) and then do your comparison `<=>`. The sort will return the original items of the enum sorted. A solution I arrived at by reading the documentation `ri Hash.sort`.