# Search with accented characters

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that stores titles and lyrics. Some songs are in spanish and contain áccénts. I'm trying to write a search method where a user can enter a word without accents. For example, let's say the title has the word "papá" in it. If the user types in "papa", it should still find that song with that word in the title.

This is what I have so far. It handles wildcards and searches through 3 columns.

```
class Song < ApplicationRecord
  def self.search(query)
    return all unless query.present?

    # for case insensitive search
    like = Rails.env.production? ? 'ILIKE' : 'LIKE'

    # for wildcards
    q = ["%#{query}%"] * 3

    # columns that I will search through song.number, song.title, song.lyrics
    search_phrase = "number #{like} ? OR title #{like} ? OR lyrics #{like} ?"

    where([search_phrase] + q)
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you using postgresql?

Comment: @kurenn I will in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't get the `COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI` or `pg` setup to work, try this. Duplicate columns, one accented, one not. Credit goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649500/4812050) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15696883/4812050) answer.

```
class Song < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :i18n

  def self.search(query)
    return all unless query.present?

    like = Rails.env.production? ? 'ILIKE' : 'LIKE'

    q = ["%#{query}%"] * 3

    search_phrase = "number #{like} ? OR ai_title #{like} ? OR ai_lyrics #{like} ?"

    where([search_phrase] + q)
  end

  def i18n
    self.ai_title = I18n.transliterate title
    self.ai_lyrics = I18n.transliterate lyrics
  end
end
```

With my migration looking like:

```
class CreateSongs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :songs do |t|
      ...
      t.string :title
      t.string :ai_title, index: true
      t.text :lyrics
      t.text :ai_lyrics, index: true
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

It works for many database setups. I find this real useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use collation:

```
search_phrase = "number #{like} ? OR title COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI #{like} ? OR lyrics #{like} ?"
```

The CI stands for case-insensitive and the AI stands for accent-insensitive.

Comment: If your MySQL server doesn't support the collations with `_ai` endings, try `_bin`. For example `utf8_bin`, `latin1_bin`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this using postgresql is to add the `unaccent` extension:

```
class AddUnaccentExtension < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    enable_extension "unaccent"
  end
end
```

And then when you want to query for results just:

```
search_phrase = "unaccent(number) #{like} unaccent(?) OR unaccent(title) #{like} unaccent(?) OR unaccent(lyrics) #{like} unaccent(?)"
```

**Have in mind this will only work on postgresql, I recommend you to use as the development database to, to prevent weird stuff from happening**