# Ruby regex /[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}/ -- "too short escaped multibyte character" error

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode

This regex works in PHP:

```
preg_match('/[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}/', '');
```

I need to port it to Ruby:

```
/[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}/ =~ ''
```

Just prints `too short escaped multibyte character: /[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}/` error.

What is wrong here? I don't understand what this error is saying. Tried to do more escaping with `\\`, but nothing.

Comment: Btw, these are symbols, that cannot be saved in MySQL. So I need to remove them or they will ruin my indexes.

Comment: Funny stuff happens whey the are inserted in MySQL. Last time my server was down for 2 hours because of them. MySQL went to endless loop, I couldn't understand what was wrong.

Comment: It seems that the code in PHP works because you somehow works on the byte representation of the character. This should not be the case in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The I think your character encoding is off. If you're trying to specify a particular unicode code point, use the `\u####` escape sequence.

However, a more robust way of handling translations between string encodings is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268289/how-to-get-rid-of-non-ascii-characters-in-ruby). That would allow you to specify an input encoding, a desired output encoding, and let Ruby do the work of removing the characters you don't want.

Comment: Actually, I don't need to mess with encoding, I just want to remove '/[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}/' characters. They are subset of Unicode that is not handled by MySQL. I don't know how convert it to the `\u####`. PHP does it as should.