# what does `too short multibyte code string in regex` mean?

Tags: regex, go, sublimetext3

I am creating a sublime text highlighting file. However, I am stuck with an error I don't fully understand. I have the following regex:

```
\x([0-9]|[A-F]|[a-f])([0-9]|[A-F]|[a-f])
```

When I try to load the file in sublime text, I get the error:

> Error in regex: too short multibyte code string in regex
>   \x([0-9]|[A-F]|[a-f])([0-9]|[A-F]|[a-f])

I have tried Googling to understand what this error means, the only thing I have come across that is relavent are the following links:

[0. github issue of the rubinius project](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/2194)

[1. stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048981/ruby-regex-xf0-xf7-x80-xbf3-too-short-escaped-multibyte-character)

[2. reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/26llao/gsub_regex_throwing_too_short_escaped_multibyte/)

Unfortunately, from those links i could only determine that that error likely caused by a character encoding [ from 1 & 2]. I now suspect that "\x" might be the problem as everything else in that regex is fine. How does one escape that character and all others like it, in particular, can a golang script be used to sanitize regexes to get rid of such problems?

Comment: just default to using backquotes (`) for regexes. That way you don't need to worry about escaping characters when you change things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you forgot to escape the `\` in `\x`.
Therefore, it's trying to parse a Unicode character escape of the form `\x1234`, and it didn't find enough numbers.