# Remove a registered trademark from the end of string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode

I am trying to remove a registered trademark from the end of a string so I can compare the two string's Levenshtein normalized distance and get an accurate number.

Does anyone know an easy way to strip the registered trademark symbol off the end of a string in Ruby?

For example:

```
example_name1 = Tylenol®
example_name2 = Tylenoloafjd
```

Comment: `mb_chars` might help you: http://apidock.com/rails/String/mb_chars

Comment: The whole point is to measure string distance so I am using misspellings as examples to user2864740

Comment: have you considered a regex to only capture the parts you want e.g. ([A-Za-z])

Comment: The only problem with that is that the unicode contains a-z chars so I am not sure how to use a regex to get around it since it contains alpha numeric characters user3334690

Comment: The purpose for Stack Overflow is to help you fix problems in code you've written. Please show us what you've tried, and show why they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can do such things:

1. Make sure you're using ruby 2.0 or later.
2. Make sure your editor is encoding the actual file in UTF-8

And then you can do it just like normal:

```
example_name1.chomp!("®")
```

Comment: You don't need the magic `#encoding: UTF-8` comment in Ruby >= 2.0, since UTF-8 is the default encoding there.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that. I revised my answer. And I can revise a lot of my code :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working in 1.9.3 so that doesn't appear to work

Comment: I ended up referencing this post and solving the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268289/how-to-get-rid-of-non-ascii-characters-in-ruby