# jekyll build error: 'control characters not allowed' in JSON file

Tags: json, ruby, jekyll, control-characters

I've written a plugin which writes JSON output to a file in the _data directory:

```
while current_page <= total_pages do

  url = 'https://web.consonance.app/api/v2/products.json'
  query = {
    'page' => "#{current_page}",
    'q[publishing_status_eq]' => '04' 
  }
  headers = {
    Authorization: "Token token=**************************"
  }
  request = HTTParty.get(url, query: query, headers: headers)

  hash = JSON.parse(request.body)

  hash['products'].each do |item|
    product_array.push(item)
  end

  current_page += 1

end

# open products.json in data dir and write array output converted from hash back to JSON

File.open("./_data/products.json", "w") { |file| 
  file.puts JSON.pretty_generate(product_array)
}
```

which puts the desired output as a JSON array in the _data directory with the following format:

```
[
  {
    "id": 100,
    "work_id": 50,
    "full_title": "Title #1"
  },
  {
    "id": 101,
    "work_id": 51,
    "full_title": "Title #2"
  }
]
```

When I try to build my site, I get the error:

```
jekyll 3.8.5 | Error:  (/Users/jamiebowman/Documents/web dev/jekyll/press/_data/products.json): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1
```

When I remove the square brackets at the beginning and the end of the JSON file, then the site builds, but I cannot properly access the data without it being an array.

What are control characters in this context and why are they stopping the site from building?

Traceback errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        30: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
        29: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
        28: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
        27: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        26: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        25: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        24: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        23: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        22: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        21: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        20: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        19: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `start'
        18: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each'
        17: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `block in start'
        16: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-livereload-0.2.2/lib/jekyll-livereload/build.rb:30:in `process'
        15: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
        14: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
        13: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
        12: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:69:in `process'
        11: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:164:in `read'
        10: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/reader.rb:18:in `read'
         9: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/readers/data_reader.rb:20:in `read'
         8: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/readers/data_reader.rb:38:in `read_data_to'
         7: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/readers/data_reader.rb:38:in `each'
         6: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/readers/data_reader.rb:46:in `block in read_data_to'
         5: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/readers/data_reader.rb:68:in `read_data_file'
         4: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.5/lib/safe_yaml/load.rb:157:in `load_file'
         3: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.5/lib/safe_yaml/load.rb:157:in `open'
         2: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.5/lib/safe_yaml/load.rb:157:in `block in load_file'
         1: from /Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.5/lib/safe_yaml/load.rb:143:in `load'
/Users/jamiebowman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.5/lib/safe_yaml/load.rb:143:in `parse': (/Users/jamiebowman/Documents/web dev/jekyll/press/_data/products.json): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

Comment: `[{'foo': 'bar'}]` is not valid json. You can verify this by pasting your JSON into https://jsonlint.com/.  What do you mean by "I cannot properly access the data"? How are you trying to access the file data?

Comment: I have pasted my JSON into jsonlint.com and it is valid. I will edit the PO with a clearer sample of data.

Comment: By accessing the data I mean via Jekyll's liquid language i.e. `{{ site.data.products }}`

Comment: please post full back trace errors

Comment: I ran `bundle exec jekyll serve --trace` and posted results. Hope that's what you meant.

Comment: @lacostenycoder I don't know why but it seems to have something to do with the number of results in the response. If I run the plugin as `current_page <= 4` with 50 results per page then the site builds successfully. Same with `current_page <= 2` with 100 results per page. So, the build is unsuccessful if more than 200 items are returned from the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on the team that maintains the API you're calling, and had the same error. It is to do with non-ASCII characters being included in the response. You can sanitize them like this:

```
problematic_string.encode(Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options)
```

where `encoding_options` are

```
  def encoding_options
    {
      :invalid           => :replace,  # Replace invalid byte sequences
      :undef             => :replace,  # Replace anything not defined in ASCII
      :replace           => '',        # Use a blank for those replacements
      :universal_newline => true       # Always break lines with \n
    }
  end
```

source: [How to get rid of non-ascii characters in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268289/how-to-get-rid-of-non-ascii-characters-in-ruby)

The `problematic_string` will likely be a long text such as a review, production blurb or other descriptive text.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a `JSON.parse` error
I don't think you want or need `pretty` format on the file. Maybe try just this:

```
File.open("./_data/products.json", "w") { |file| 
  file.write product_array.to_json
}
```

But your error seems like it might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/504) so maybe have a look at the fork posted in the issue to see if it helps.

Comment: the `.to_json` method results in the same error, but I will try again with the forked Jekyll version